# Option data is not updating in database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

While editing if I choose another option and click on save button, it is not updating in database.

Edit blade page

```
<select class="form-control" name="status">
    <option value="">Select Status</option>
    <option value="0" {{($inspection_schedules->status == '0')? 'selected': ''}}>Scheduled</option>
    <option value="1" {{($inspection_schedules->status == '1')? 'selected': ''}}>Inprogress</option>
    <option value="2" {{($inspection_schedules->status == '2')? 'selected': ''}}>Completed</option>
</select>
```

Controller

```
public function postUpdateInspectionSchedule(Request $request, $id){

    $request->validate([
       'user_id' => 'required',
       'inspection_date' => 'required|date_format:m/d/Y',
    ]);

    $inspection_schedules = InspectionSchedule::findOrFail($id);
    $inspection_schedules->user_id = $request->user_id;
    $inspection_schedules->inspection_id = $id;
    $inspection_schedules->inspection_date = Carbon::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $request->inspection_date)->format('Y-m-d');
    $inspection_schedules->status = $request->status;
    $status = $inspection_schedules->save();
    if($status == 1){
        Session::flash('msg', 'Inspection Updated successfully.');
    }else{
        Session::flash('msg', 'Something went wrong, Try again later!');
    }
    return redirect('/admin/inspection/schedule/edit/'.$id);
}
```

Route

```
Route::get('/inspection/schedule/edit/{id}', 'InspectionController@getEditInspectionSchedule');
Route::post('/inspection/schedule/edit/{id}', 'InspectionController@postUpdateInspectionSchedule');
```

Comment: Why do you have `dd($request->all());` as the first line of the code - do you know what `dd()` does?

Comment: what is output from dd($request) ? please show me

Comment: array:4 [▼
  "_token" => "7OkJEaOWimsTtTzqpG7qHvCdeLHGuaCSEReWMOte"
  "user_id" => "2"
  "inspection_date" => "2019-09-17"
  "status" => "1"
]

Answer (score 0):

Check type status in database 
Because if in db type was enum or int so you need to cast request to same type

Comment: db type is enum

Comment: what's enum values if values doesn't much status (0,1,2) so that not saved so you should convert it to same type

Comment: enum value is 0,1,2 and default value 0

Comment: $inspection_schedules->status = strval($request->status); //Converted to string

Comment: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails